# Matching a regular expression on multiline not working

Tags: java, regex

I have the following file contents and I'm trying to match a reg explained below:

```
-- file.txt (doesn't match multi-line) -- 
test

On blah

more blah wrote:
---------------
```

If I read the file contents from above to a String and try to match the "On...wrote:" part I cannot get a match:

```
    // String text = <file contents from above>
    Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(On\\s(.+)wrote:)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
       System.out.println("Never gets HERE???");
    }
```

The above regex works fine if the contents of the file are on one line:

```
-- file2.txt (matches on single line) -- 
test

On blah more blah wrote: On blah more blah wrote:
---------------
```

How do I get the multiline to work and the single line all in one regex (or two for that matter)?  Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Pattern.MULTILINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) just tells Java to accept the anchors `^` and `$` to match at the start and end of each line.

Add the [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag to allow the dot `.` character to match newline characters. This is done using the [bitwise inclusive OR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) `|` operator

```
Pattern PATTERN = 
    Pattern.compile("^(On\\s(.+)wrote:)$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL );
```

Comment: Fantastic! Worked the first time as advertised! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of matching `\S` (*non-whitespace*) and `\s` (*whitespace*)

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(On\\s([\\S\\s]*?)wrote:)");
```

See [live regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/dI0kL8)

Example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class rTest {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    String s = "test\n\n"
             + "On blah\n\n"
             + "more blah wrote:\n";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(On\\s([\\S\\s]*?)wrote:)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
  }
}
```